# GluonFx server socket communication

Tags: javafx, native, gluon, gluonfx

I have JavaFX application that based on GluonFX framework.
It creates simple Server Socket:

```
public class Application {

private static final int SOCKET_PORT = 40009;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        try (ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket()) {
            ss.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", SOCKET_PORT));
            System.out.println("Server started");
            ss.accept();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Something go wrong");
    }
}
```

When I run application as java process (for example in intellij idea)

I can ping port 40009 by command:

```
netstat -vanp tcp | grep 40009
```

But when I create native runner for this app and run it. This port is free.
In this time an app works correctly but port is free.
Why port is free for native run ?

P.S. I tried to reproduce following case for Graal VM and it works correctly.